# Access public static member from visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an Apex class as follows:

```
public class Util {
    public static ID AccountId {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I am trying to reference this from a `Visualforce` page without luck.  How would I go about getting this to work?

```
<!-- this works -->
<apex:outputLabel value="{!$Api.Session_ID}" />
<!-- why not this? -->
<apex:outputLabel value="{!$Util.AccountId}" />
```

As an FYI, the error message I am getting back is as follows:

> Unknown property 'MyController.Util'

Comment: Only global variable can be referencering like that ({!$Util.AccountId}). But I reckon that would be really nice to have. {!$Apexclass.Utils.AccountId}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can't reference a variable from another class into your visualforce page. You can only reference variables from your controller.

If you're using a standard controller then you can do the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Util">
    <apex:outputText value="{!AccountId}" />
</apex:page>
```

Alternatively, if you're having a custom controller, you can make your Util class virtual or abstract and then extend it into your custom controller:

```
public with sharing class MyCustomController extends Util
{
    // your code
}
```

and your page will looke like:

```
<apex:page controller="MyCustomController">
    <apex:outputText value="{!AccountId}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Or an extension. You could write an accessor method to access the static value from the controller, too.

Comment: I've modified my question slightly to make it a little less confusing.  The variable `mAccountId` needs to be private, but that is sort of besides the point.  In VF you can access other global variables like `{!$Api.Session_ID}`.  Is it not possible to define your own?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the global variables are pre-defined and you can't specify your own one. As @sfdcfox mentioned, you can add an extension to your visualforce page and reference the variable from the other class. Please see updated answer in a couple of mins